# Conditional skin file in ASP.Net Theme based off of browser

Tags: asp.net, browser, themes, skinning

Is there a way to use a skin file in a theme only when a certain browser is used?

The theme stays the same, I just want skin A to apply when a certain browser is used, and skin B when another browser is used.  I know I can have server-side code to check and then set the SkinId of the control to either or, but is there another, more global way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [test for what browser the user is using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yekbd5b.aspx), and then [set the theme programatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx35bd89.aspx) that way.

An example might be:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    System.Web.HttpBrowserCapabilities browser = Request.Browser;
    if (browser.ToUpper().IndexOf("IE") >= 0)
    {
            Page.Theme = "BlueTheme";
    }
    else
    {
            Page.Theme = "PinkTheme";
    }
}
```

Comment: While the question was about changing the skin, and not the theme, the solution given above would be the same.  ACCEPTED!